# How to define a Regular Expression in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

my problem is that I need to define a regular expression in Jmeter in order to make a DELETE method in my page. The real problem is that I cannot delete a specific token with an ID.

I defined a regular Expression which his name is "uidprofesor" that refers to the token. This token, when I try to delete it manually and catch the request, I get the following code in the Raw Response Data:

```
{"headers":
  {"Location":["/api/profesores/5c745065-3155-4ff7-ac65-7699a36f611c"],
              "X-afppApp-alert":["afppApp.profesor.created"],
              "X-afppApp-params":["5c745065-3155-4ff7-ac65-7699a36f611c"]},
              "body":{"id":"5c745065-3155-4ff7-ac65-7699a36f611c",
              "nif":"12345678Q",
              "name":"jmeter_122",
              "firstSurname":"jmeter_122",
              "secondSurname":"",
              "address":"",
              "postalCode":"",
              "telephone":"",
              "mobile":"",
              "email":"",
              "dateInsert":"24/04/2019"
  },
 "statusCode":"CREATED",
 "statusCodeValue":201
}
```

, where I assume that "5c745065-3155-4ff7-ac65-7699a36f611c" is the ID.

If I wanted to define "uidprofesor" to catch that ID what should I define in the regular erxpression?

I tried defining the regular expression like:

```
{"headers":"(.+?)"
```

```
{"headers":{"Location":"(.+?)"
```

```
{"Location":"(.+?)"
```

But nothing. It shows the Default Value: NOT_FOUND and does not delete the selected token.

I let you here some extra info:

```
regular expression ${uidprofesor} = {"headers":"(.+?)"
```

In the HTTP Request the Path is:

```
https://desa1eap7.asturias.es/afpp-back/${uidprofesor}
```

If I do the deletion manually, in Google Chrome Developer Tab, It returns:

```
Requested URL: https://desa1eap7.asturias.es/afpp-back/api/profesores
```

If you need more info just ask it. Thanks.

Comment: Your regex patterns are just wrong, e.g. the first one should be `\{"headers":"(.+?)"`.  But in any case, you really should be using a JSON parser to search JSON content, _not_ a regex.

Comment: I will try it right now.

Comment: Improved formatting and corrected some typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jMeter JSON Extractor: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

It uses JsonPath https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

```
$.headers.Location[0]
```

Check online here https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Consider accept my answer and/or upvote. Thanks :-)